# Odd Object Quirk - JavaScript - Beginner

Tags: javascript, object

I'm reading an [article](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/5589-just-javascript-in-the-beginning-was-the-object.html) that says that `{}` is a valid JavaScript program.

I tried it and it worked fine.

Then I tried this and it worked:

`{name:'Lord Stark'}` <--- the entire program (not assigning it to a variable or anything)

---

*But* then I tried the following and it threw an error at the comma.

`{name:'Lord Stark',reignsOver:'Winterfell'}`  <--- again this is the entire program

---

My question is, why does a plain object with more than one property (and consequently a comma), return an error unless assigned to a variable when an object with only a single entry does not?

Comment: The piece of code you posted works just fine. Both the snippets execute without error to me. Must have been a typo?

Comment: That's not an object with a property. It's a block containing a statement with a label. Notice that the output of the program `{name:'Lord Stark'}` is `"Lord Stark"`, not `{name: "Lord Stark"}`.

Comment: Also, I can't find anywhere on that page that says that `{}` is a valid JavaScript program. It says that `{}` is a JavaScript object literal, but an object literal is not a program.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: @RaymondChen inside the paragraph that starts with this bolded subtitle "In JavaScript everything is an object"

Comment: That sentence is being loose with the word "everything". What it's trying to say is that everything you can put in a variable is an object. But there are things you can't put in variables (like statements).

Comment: Note that `{` and `}` are [*punctuators*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-punctuators), they are used for blocks and object literals. Which one they represent depends on where they appear in the code.

Comment: That's a JSON parsed Object.Execute this code and you will see for yourself : `console.dir({name:'Lord Stark',reignsOver:'Winterfell'});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{}` is an empty block.

`{name: 'Lord Stark'}` is a block with a label, and a string (which will do nothing).

`{name: 'Lord Stark', reignsOver: 'Winterfell'}` is a block, which starts off with a label again, then has string which will do nothing, then a comma operator, then an undefined variable `reignsOver`, then a colon, which is invalid syntax.

The `{}` will be interpreted as an object only in an expression context, such as `var x = {name: 'Lord Stark', reignsOver: 'Winterfell'};`.

Note that the console may exercise some smarts and try to figure out what you are doing, and might handle `{a: 1, b:2}` "correctly" as an object. To see how something is executed as a block, you could try typing in `if (1) {name: 'Lord Stark', reignsOver: 'Winterfell'}`.

The article you reference is not exactly right:

> The curly brackets mean that this is an object and it can contain other objects within the curly brackets. Believe it or not this is a valid JavaScript program. If you run it, it creates an empty object which promptly disappears again as the program comes to an end.

Actually, a stand-alone JS program of the form `{}` is **not** an object, it's an empty block.

Some references:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label